# How large file is considered to be large to process it using itext with RandomAccessFileOrArray?

Tags: java, file, pdf, itext

I am attempting to process multiple sizes of pdf files, so the size of the file can be as small as 10kb to as big as 1.5gb. So I am unsure when to load the file using

```
reader = new PdfReader(Files.readAllBytes((new File(filenameSource)).toPath()))
```

and when to load the file using

```
reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(filenameSource),null);
```

Basically, What I want to ask is how big the file size will be to considered as large file and get processed with second option?

Comment: Given your description, I believe you are asking a question that is too broad to be unequivocally answered. If you narrow your question to include what you're concerned about in the context with which your program operates, then you might get a good answer.

Comment: You shouldn't load the file entirely into memory at all, whatever its size. Surely `PdfReader` has a constructor that takes a `File` or a filename as argument, or an input stream? Not just a byte array?

Comment: Yes, indeed `PdfReader` does have `File`, `InputStream`, `IRandomAccessSource` (bytes) and  `String` (filename), see https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.1.11/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfReader.html

Comment: @MarquisofLorne The default is that it will try to `mmap` the file. It's my general impression that on a 64-bit JVM this should always be fine.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- `Files.readAllBytes()` reads the entire file into memory. He should not use it at all. This is what he is asking about.